# upload button in SharePoint designer

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server

I need to upload folders and files to style library from SharePoint designer, I can't find the upload button to do that!!!

Am I missing something?

I am using SharePoint designer 2013

Comment: you can easily, click on *preview in browser* button to open the document library in browse, then use *open with explorer* to copy and paste your files, Is it what you need?

Comment: Not exactly, I want to upload files from SharePoint designer itself!

Comment: Okay, try to use import files button!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is **no** a frank upload button in SharePoint Designer!

But you can performs the same upload functionality to upload files or folders from your PC through sharePoint designer by doing the following:

1. Using the **Import files** button to upload files or folder from your PC.

   [image]
2. You can also **drag and drop** your files and folder directly to a library in SharePoint Designer! it performs the same import functionality!